# Plotting a line graph by datetime with a histogram/bar graph by date

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, histogram

I'm relatively new to R and could really use some help with some pretty basic `ggplot2` work.

I'm trying to visualize total number of submissions on a graph, showing the overall total in a line graph and the daily total in a histogram (or bar graph) on top of it. I'm not sure how to add breaks or bins to the histogram so that it takes the submission datetime column and makes each bar the daily total.

I tried adding a column that converts the datetime into just date and plots based on that, but I'd really like the line graph to include the time.

Here's what I have so far:

```
df <- df %>%
mutate(datetime = lubridate::mdy_hm(datetime))%>%
mutate(date = lubridate::as_date(datetime))

#sort by datetime 
df <- df %>%
  arrange(datetime)

#add total number of submissions
df <- df %>%
  mutate(total = row_number())

#ggplot
line_plus_histo <- df%>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_histogram(data = df, aes(x=datetime)) +
  geom_line(data = df, aes(x=datetime, y=total), col = "red") +
  stat_bin(data = df, aes(x=date), geom = "bar") +
  labs(
    title="Submissions by Day", 
    x="Date",
    y="Submissions",
    legend=NULL)

line_plus_histo
```

As you can see, I'm also calculating the total number of submissions by sorting by time and then adding a column with the row number. So if you can help me use a better method I'd really appreciate it.

Please, find below the line plus histogram of time v. submissions:

[image]

[Here's the pastebin link with my data](https://pastebin.com/szHRqZhn)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extend your data manipulation by:

```
df <- df |>
  mutate(datetime = lubridate::mdy_hm(datetime)) |>
  arrange(datetime) |>
  mutate(midday = as_datetime(floor_date(as_date(datetime), unit = "day") + 0.5)) |>
  mutate(totals = row_number()) |>
  group_by(midday) |>
  mutate(N = n())|>
  ungroup()
```

then use `midday` for bars and `datetime` for line:

```r
df%>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_bar(data = df, aes(x = midday)) +
  geom_line(data = df, aes(x=datetime, y=totals), col = "red") +
  labs(
    title="Submissions by Day", 
    x="Date",
    y="Submissions",
    legend=NULL)
```

[image]

PS. Sorry for Polish locales on X axis.

PS2. With `geom_bar` it looks much better

<sup>Created on 2022-02-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>